# Why is $\int 1/(z-3) \, dz = 0$ on the circle $|z-1| = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have two reasonings:

(Standard reasoning): Since $1/(z-3)$ is holomorphic in $|z-1| \leq 1$, by Cauchy-Goursat theorem, $\int 1/(z-3) \,dz = 0$.

(Other reasoning): Observe that $ \int 1/(z^2) \,dz$ = 0  on $|z-1|=1$ even though at $0, 1/z^2$ is not holomorphic. The reason this happens is because we can find a primitive of $1/(z^2)$ (by intuition) and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to arrive at the conclusion. Now we cannot repeat this trick for $1/z$ because there is no such primitive (our intuition of $\log z$ fails because it's not continuous) exist. One of the reasons for $\log z$ not being continuous is $0$ is the branch point. So coming back to my example, since the branch point has shifted to $3$, and the curve is $|z-1|=1$, I can make $\log z$ continuous and hence $1/(z-3)$ has a primitive (which is $\log z$) and hence by fundamental theorem of calculus its equal to $0$.

Is my other reasoning right?

P.S Can someone show me $\int 1/(z-3) \,dz = 0$  by explicitly evaluating the integral on the contour $|z-1|=1$ without any reference to complex analysis.

Comment: The "standard reasoning" proof owuld be clearer if you said the function is holomorphic in the disk $|z-1|\leq1$.  To say it's holomorphic in $|z-1|=1$ could be misunderstood to mean only that it's holomorphic near the boundary circle of the disk, rather than throughout the whole disk.  (And you need it to be holomorphic in the interior of the disk in order to apply Cauchy-Goursat.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Point noted. Although I am more concerned about my second reasoning, any comments on that?

Comment: The second proof is fine; the branch cut for $\ln(z-3)$ can be taken to run from $3$ to $\infty$ along the positive $x$-axis, where it won't interfere with the contour of your integral.

Comment: Perhaps that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2556221/446262) computation will interest you. It's about computing (without using Complex Analysis) $\int_\gamma\frac1{z+2}\,\mathrm dz$ where $\gamma$ is the curve $|z|=3$. Unlike the integral from your question, this integral is *not* $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Here is a "direct" proof that the integral is 0. The integral is equivalent to $\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{z-2}dz$. Now let $\gamma : [0,2\pi) \to \{|z| = 1\}$ be $\gamma(t) = \cos t + i\sin t$. Then $\gamma'(t) = -\sin t + i\cos t$. By definition, our integral is $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t + i\cos t}{\cos t + i\sin t - 2}dt$. Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $(\cos t -2)-i\sin t$ gives $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin t (\cos t -2)+\sin t \cos t + i\cos t (\cos t-2) - i \sin^2 t}{5-4\cos t}$. Look at the real part and substitute $y = t-\pi$ to get that the real part is $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{2\sin y\cos y + 2\sin y}{5+4\cos y} dy$. This is $0$ since the integrand is odd. I will let you handle the imaginary part in a similar way.